# Which option is true if two function $f$ ang $g$ are differentiable for the following properties?

Tags: calculus

Suppose f and g both are differentiable. Now $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ for all $x < 1$ and $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$ for all $x > 1.$ Then

a) if $f(1) \geq g(1)$, then $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x$
b) if $f(1) \leq g(1)$, then $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x$
c) $f(1) \leq g(1)$
d) $f(1) \geq g(1)$.

Please help me out.

Comment: Study the function $f-g$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, as suggested in the comment above, so $h$ is differentiable and continuous everywhere.

You know that $h^{\prime}(x)=f^{\prime}(x)-g^{\prime}(x)\le0$ for $x<1$, so $h$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,1]$.

Similarly, $h^{\prime}(x)=f^{\prime}(x)-g^{\prime}(x)\ge0$ for $x>1$, so $h$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$.

Therefore you can conclude that $h(1)$ is the minimum value for $h$.

(Now determine which choice follows from this.)